Stripe Payment Integration Failing in India with Error: 'An error occurred while processing your payment'
I'm encountering an issue with Stripe payment integration in my Laravel application when processing payments from users in India. The error message displayed is:
"An error occurred while processing your payment. Try again later or with a different payment method."
This issue appears to be specific to payments originating from India, and I suspect it may be related to the recent regulations around online payments, such as the requirement for 3D Secure and new mandates on recurring payments.
To address this, I have taken the following steps:
Enabled 3D Secure on my Stripe account.
Updated my code to handle the new Indian regulations for recurring payments.
Despite implementing these changes, payments continue to fail with the same error message. I expected the payments to process successfully after these adjustments, but they are still being rejected.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have insights on additional steps or configurations needed to comply with Indian payment regulations on Stripe? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
image description here
